# git removes file after checkout

Tags: windows, git

When I switch to specific branch that contains specific file (`MegaFeature.cs` in branch `MegaRelease` for example) I see `MegaFeature.cs` marked as removed and doesn't exists in FS.
I renamed that file and commit it with new name and all became right (git doesn't remove it after checkout to `MegaRelease`) but now if I rename it again to `MegaFeature.cs` and commit that, then switch to another branch and go back to `MegaRelease`, git still removing that file.

---

**Windows 10**

**git version 2.10.2.windows.1**

How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Check your git hook, perhaps you might have rule that this file is not suppose to check-in?

Comment: @LethalProgrammer no, a don't have any hooks :(